# How to normalise inconsistent category labels in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

Table has text labels for category identification
The spelling has changed over time
I want to normalise the text labels when I count the records in each category
So for example I have The category labels:
'Ready to go' and 'Readytogo' 
But I also have another text value abc that I want to replace with Abcd
The rest Inwant to keep in my Groupby and Count

How can I count these in the new group names in Teradata?
At the moment I'm using case statements for the ones I'm okay with, then using OREPLACE to switch one of the values but how do I nest it so that I can OREPLACE 2 or more values with 2 or more new ones?  Is OREPLACE the best function to use here?

Thanks

Comment: Please include a reproducible example. Data helps illustrate your point and demonstrate our answers.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies I have managed to solve it using multiple WHEN, THEN clauses as part of 1 case statement

This changes the text value ax to bn along with Fx to BM for example, as required

The OREPLACE function was not recognised in the release of Teradata that I am using

I will specify question better next time

Thanks